Flutter Riverpod: Getting an error Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel is not registered inside GetIt
I am using flutter so I was using provider state management, now I am using riverpod state management for ,my code, so I am still a beginner when it comes to riverpod.
I have this code, where I want to press the button, it must navigate. Now, the issue it is complaining about the bad state: GetIt my GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel is not registered inside Getit. I cannot get through this issue, can I please get some assistance.
My view model
golf_leaderboard_summary_view.dart
class GolfLeaderboardSummaryState {
  final List<Rounds> standings;
  final String? activeTab;
  final String title;
  final SportsTourModel sportsTourModel;
  final Tournament? golfLeaderboardList;

  GolfLeaderboardSummaryState({
    this.standings = const [],
    this.activeTab,
    this.title = 'Leaderboard Summary',
    required this.sportsTourModel,
    this.golfLeaderboardList,
  });

  GolfLeaderboardSummaryState copyWith({
    List<Rounds>? standings,
    String? activeTab,
    String? title,
    SportsTourModel? sportsTourModel,
    Tournament? golfLeaderboardList,
  }) {
    return GolfLeaderboardSummaryState(
      standings: standings ?? this.standings,
      activeTab: activeTab ?? this.activeTab,
      title: title ?? this.title,
      sportsTourModel: sportsTourModel ?? this.sportsTourModel,
      golfLeaderboardList: golfLeaderboardList ?? this.golfLeaderboardList,
    );
  }
}

class GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel extends StateNotifier<GolfLeaderboardSummaryState> {
  final Tournament? golfLeaderboardList;
  final GolfScoreSummary? golfScoreSummary;
  final GolfRepository? golfRepository;

  GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel({this.golfLeaderboardList, this.golfScoreSummary, this.golfRepository})
      : super(GolfLeaderboardSummaryState(sportsTourModel: SportsTourModel())) {
    _init();
  }

  final String title = 'Leaderboard Summary';
  final SportsTourModel sportsTourModel = SportsTourModel();
  // late GolfRepository golfRepository;

  void _init() {
    //  _clearStandings();
    _getLeaderboardSummaryList();
    _setSportsTourModel();
  }

  RxList<Rounds> standings = <Rounds>[].obs;

  // void _clearStandings() {
  //   state = state.copyWith(standings: []);
  // }

  void _getLeaderboardSummaryList() {
    if (golfLeaderboardList != null) {
      for (final Leaderboard group in golfLeaderboardList!.leaderboard!) {
        if (group.rounds != null && group.rounds!.isNotEmpty) {
          standings.value = group.rounds!;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  String? _activeTab;
  String? get activeTab => _activeTab;

  final tabSwitchController = Get.put(TabSwitchController());

  void switchToTab(String? tab) {
    _activeTab = tab;
    if (tab != null) {
      tabSwitchController.activeTab.value = _activeTab!;
    }
    // state = state.copyWith(activeTab: tab);
  }

 

  void _setSportsTourModel() {
    sportsTourModel.classification = 'tour';
    sportsTourModel.id = golfScoreSummary!.tour!.id;
    sportsTourModel.name = golfScoreSummary!.tour!.name;
    sportsTourModel.image = golfScoreSummary!.tour!.icon;
    sportsTourModel.sport = 'golf';
    sportsTourModel.entityType = TourEntityTypes.golfEntityType;
  }
}

// Define a provider for Tournament
final tournamentProvider = Tournament();

// Define a provider for GolfScoreSummary
final golfScoreSummaryProvider = GolfScoreSummary();

final golfLeaderboardSummaryControllerProvider = Provider.autoDispose<GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel>((_) {
  return GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel(
    golfLeaderboardList: locator<GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel>().golfLeaderboardList,
    golfScoreSummary: locator<GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel>().golfScoreSummary,
    golfRepository: locator<GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel>().golfRepository,
  );
});

My widget
golf_leaderboard_summary_widget.dart
class GolfLeaderboardSummaryWidget extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final Tournament? golfLeaderboardList;
  final GolfScoreSummary? golfScoreSummary;
  final bool? isCurrentStanding;

  const GolfLeaderboardSummaryWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.golfLeaderboardList,
    required this.golfScoreSummary,
    this.isCurrentStanding,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GolfLeaderboardSummaryWidgetState createState() => _GolfLeaderboardSummaryWidgetState();
}

class _GolfLeaderboardSummaryWidgetState extends ConsumerState<GolfLeaderboardSummaryWidget> {
  //late GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel currentStandingsController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final currentStandingsControllerx = ref.watch(golfLeaderboardSummaryControllerProvider);
    final GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel currentStandingsController = GolfLeaderboardSummaryViewModel(
      golfLeaderboardList: widget.golfLeaderboardList,
      golfScoreSummary: widget.golfScoreSummary,
      // golfRepository: currentStandingsControllerx.golfRepository,
    );
Widget _cardFooter(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Divider(
          color: SuperSportColorScheme.spanishGray.withOpacity(0.4),
          thickness: 0.5,
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 48,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              ref.read(golfLeaderboardSummaryControllerProvider).switchToTab('LeaderboardList'); //the error is thrown here
            }},

So, can I please get some assistance here on how can I go about this with the riverpod clean architecture.
Your help will be appreciated.
Regards
